# How do I enable SSL for a subdomain that points to an Amazon EC2 instance (Elastic IP)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, netlify

I'm trying to enable SSL on a subdomain from a domain I purchased from Google Domains (Managed with Netlify DNS). The domain is currently pointing to a static react app hosted by Netlify (it has SSL).

The subdomain (api.example.com) pointing to an elastic IP associated with an EC2 instance doesn't seem to be working when I try to access it with HTTPS (api.example.com’s server IP address could not be found.) but works with HTTP.

Does anyone know of a way I could use that SSL certificate I got from Netlify on the subdomain pointing to my aws instance?

I'm using only an A record for the subdomain -> elastic ip. For the purpose of getting everything to work, I've enabled all inbound/outbound ports for all traffic types on my instance security group.

Comment: Have you opened up port 443 as well as port 80? Have installed the certificate on the server? What is running on there? An easier option might be to put something in front of EC2, maybe cloudfront  to handle TLS termination.

Comment: +1 to Will Munn’s questions. What is running on the EC2 instance. Also, are you saying that when you go to http://api.example.com in Chrome, it works (and what does “works” mean, what happens when you do this?) but when you go to https://api.example.com, your browser says server IP address could not be found? That sounds very surprising, resolving a server address (DNS) has nothing to do with whether or not the request is HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: Also are you sure it wasn’t just a matter of DNS propagation lag? If you quickly go back and forth between trying http vs https does it go back and forth between “working” and not working?